# Transparent background with GD in PHP

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to create a chart with PHP and GD. The chart is already working but I
can't get the background to be transparent (with anti-aliasing).

I want to place an anti-aliased line on a gradient background (this is the HTML background) but it shows some white pixels (see the image link and my code below). Is it possible to do this with GD? I have searched a lot on the Internet but can't find any solutions.

[image: Image showing aliasing problem]

PHP

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(1000, 1000);

imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagealphablending($img, true);

$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 127); 
$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0); 

imagefill($img, 0, 0, $color);

imageantialias($img, true);
imageline($img, 10, 10, 500, 20, $red);

header("content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img); 
imagedestroy($img); 
?>
```

HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background:url('/Image/background.png');
    }
</style>

<img src="./example.php" />
```

Comment: My experience is that GD is terrible with anti-aliasing, have you considered using ImageMagick?

Comment: Not really (because my Chart builder is almost finished in GD). Is the anti alias better there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP manual basically states that you cannot:

> **It does not support alpha components.** It works using a direct blend
>   operation. It works only with truecolor images.
>
> Thickness and styled are not supported.
>
> **Using antialiased primitives with transparent background color can end
>   with some unexpected results. The blend method uses the background
>   color as any other colors. The lack of alpha component support does
>   not allow an alpha based antialiasing method.**

http://es.php.net/imageantialias

So unless someone comes with third-party code or some witty hacks, you're out of luck.

Comment: Oke thanks for helping! I will search for another solution then.